# Saving an .eps file with reduced number of colors

Tags: gnuplot, eps

The aim is to produce an .eps file which is not coded with RGB 8-bits per channel, but less (to save diskspace).

To limit number of colors I used in Gnuplot:

```
set palette maxcolor XXX
```

which worked and reduce number of colors on the high-resolution plot, I produce using terminal epslatex, pm3d in Gnuplot.

Although the plot itself changes (with respect to the one without maxcolor limitation) and it has limited number of colors, the file is still huge. After inspecting I see why:

```
identify output.eps
```

It is coded with True Color:

```
Type: TrueColorAlpha
red: 8-bit
green: 8-bit
blue: 8-bit
alpha: 8-bit
```

so occupies more space than it needs to. ImageMagick tricks doesn't work, beacuse they render the .eps and spoil vector information.
Do you know how to save/convert this .eps file with less bits per channel?

Comment: Do you plot with `pm3d` or `image` plotting style? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131106/33933 for some background information.

Comment: I was using pm3d, I added this info to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Christof's comment is very helpful, in fact just changing "pm3d" to "image" reduces file size from 8MB to 300K and the quality exceeds the expectation, because I now can even use True Color (no maxcolor limit). 
Thanks a lot, Christoph!